# How to set up TeamCity for multiple applications with shared code

Tags: svn, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

Currently we have an SVN structure like this:

```
svn
-trunk
--shared_library
--shared_library
--application_solution
---application_project
-branches
--version_number
```

So at the root of trunk we have all the shared libraries in their own folders, and then the distinct applications have their own solution folders.

Most of these applications use shared libraries.

So we have a lot of distinct applications that can be used independently of each other, but are all bundled up in to a single WiX Burn Package for deployment.

What would be the best way to structure this in TeamCity?

Would we have one project for the root with different build configurations for individual applications? Would we make different subprojects for each project? or each solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the applications can be used independently of each other, you should create targets per application and run CI on them. This will give you much required flexibility and help you setup Continuos Integration and Deployment (usually refrred to as CI/CD)

You can have a separate target that packages the artefacts into the Wix  and runs tests on them for CI/CD purposes but that will come once you start testing and integrating